# Xampp installation error: Error running cmd.exe/C start/ MIN net

Tags: php, windows, cmd, xampp

I'm trying to install xampp on my windows, but I encountered this error:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not be complete correctly Error running cmd.exe/C start/MIN net stop *** unknown variable apache_unique_service_name***: child killed: segmentation violation

I tried searching solutions online but to no avail. Hoping someone has a solution to this error.

Comment: Are you trying to install the latest version?

Comment: @MatteoMeil Yes

Comment: Which extensions are you installing?

Comment: @MatteoMeil I'm not sure how to check what extensions I've installed. I just install all the default options available from the software on https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: I just downloaded and installed the latest version and I had no problems with it. I suggest you to first uninstall the version you have with a program that deep scans residual files (I'm using IOBitUninstaller Portable), then try redownload and reinstall xampp, starting installer as administrator. Don't forget to restart you PC before reinstalling

Comment: @MatteoMeil I tried all the steps as you mentioned but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Where are you installing xampp? In `C:\xampp` or another directory?